# Java: Split ResultSet into multiple arrays (based on timestamp)

Tags: java, arrays, split, timestamp, resultset

I have a ResultSet from a SQL query. Each ResultSet contains a Unix-Timestamp and a double value:

```
double timeStamp = resultSet.getDouble(1);
double value     = resultSet.getDouble(2);
```

I would like to create (either before or while iterating through the ResultSet) several arrays, each of them representing a range between two time timestamps.
Each double/double pair of the resultSet should be put into one of those arrays.

For example, if the lowest timestamp would be 1366816115 and the highest 1366848754, I would like to create arrays with a timerange of one hour (60 minutes) and put each double/double pair into one of those arrays, provided the timestamp of the ResultSet matches.

WHAT IS AN EFFICIENT WAY TO DO THIS IN JAVA? I tried several approaches but each time I start fiddling about it and eventually get confused.

If there is a certain keyword I should look up, I would be happy about that, too.

Thanks in advance for reading and any help.

EDIT:
pasha701 answer works great, for completeness, here is how I calculate periodStart:

```
Double key = new Double(timeStamp - (timeStamp % granularityInSeconds));
```

where timeStamp = unix timestamp (divide Java timestamps by 1000) and granularityInSeconds=which range should an array cover, i.e. granularityInSeconds = (60*60) will create arrays covering an hour.

Thanks a lot, pasha701!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void execute ()  {
    Map<Double, List<Pair>> arrayMap = new HashMap<Double, List<Pair>>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        double timeStamp = resultSet.getDouble(1);
        double value = resultSet.getDouble(2);

        Double key = getPeriondStart(timeStamp);
        List<Pair> list = arrayMap.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Pair>();
            arrayMap.put(key, list);
        }
        list.add(new Pair(timeStamp, value));
    }

    // arrayMap contains arrays separated by periods
}

// shrink parameter to Unix-Timestamp period (hour) begining
Double getPeriondStart(double timeStamp) {
    return ...;
}

class Pair {
    double timeStamp;
    double value;

    public Pair(double timeStamp, double value) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great approach, thank you very, very much! I can't upvote, not enough reputation...